# Tons of unknown connections in nethogs

Tags: ubuntu, networking, netstat, malware

I am seeing hundreds of different connections to the same ip and port scrolling by when running nethogs. Occasionally the foreign IP and port will change (not always 80, but sometimes). I've noticed that my router CPU usage jumps to 100% when these huge bursts of connections happen, so I'm fairly certain that this massive spike keeps overloading the router and essentially making my network useless for up to a full 60 seconds.

[image: wat]

Things I've tried:

- `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep $whateverip`: nothing
- `sudo netstat --inet -ap | grep $whateverip`: nothing
- `sudo lsof -i | grep $whateverport`: by the time this finishes, the port and IP have changed again

This may just be paranoia, but I swear it seems like every time I try to dig into more info on the connection, the port and IP change, so my command gives me nothing.

Am I dealing with something evil living inside my server? Or is there some more benign explanation that I'm missing in my limited networking knowledge?

Also note that this is an Ubuntu server with no UI, so it's not me chasing around someone just browsing reddit.

Comment: any luck with that? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Have temporarily solved it by filtering the outgoing traffic to the ip in question, by typing in the following command:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d <ip-adress>/24 -j DROP
sudo iptables-save
```

The "/24" means it only cares about the first three numbers in the ip-adress. The problem is that it keeps coming back with new ip-addresses. I have added 12 such lines to iptables now, and it has been a few hours since a flood, but I expect it to happen again tomorrow morning. It seems to intensify in the night/early morning (CET) for me. Most, but not all of them are located in China. I think this article might be relevant, but I'm not sure:

http://www.michael-joost.de/dnsterror.html

Please let me know if you figure it out. Next up for me is to try changing the password on my root account and see if that helps.

Comment: The next morning I had to add three more lines. Let's see how many tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

To identify the processes you have to be `sudo` and use `-np` instead

```
sudo netstat -np | grep <ip>
```

> --numeric, -n
> Show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or user names

Since it does not need to resolve IP addresses, that's exactly what you want.

But then you want to see which program it is

> -p, --program
> Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.